# Solve $\lim_{x \rightarrow 1}\frac{e^{x-1}-2x+1}{x-1}$ without using L'Hopital's rule

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

I know that I can solve this making $f(x) = e^{x-1}-2x$ and then applying the formula of the derivative to the expression $\frac{f(x)-f(1)}{x-1}$, so that the answer is $f(1)'$. However, my book has the following hint about this exercise:

> Start by rewriting the expression as the sum of two fractions that
>   tend both to indeterminations of the type $\frac{0}{0}$.

So I tried:

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 1}\frac{e^{x-1}-2x+1}{x-1} = \frac{e^{x-1}+1-2x}{x-1} = \frac{e^{x-1}+1}{x-1} - \frac{2x}{x-1}  = ???$$

Which both tend to $\frac{1}{0}$. How do I solve this using my book's hint?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:**
$$ \lim_{x\rightarrow1}\frac{e^{x-1}-2x+1}{x-1}=\lim_{x\rightarrow1}\frac{e^{x-1}\color{red}{-1}-2x+1\color{red}{+1}}{x-1}=\lim_{x\rightarrow1}\left[\frac{e^{x-1}-1}{x-1}-2\frac{x-1}{x-1}\right] $$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Write as $$\dfrac{e^{x-1}-1}{x-1}-2$$

Comment: How did you get that expression?

Comment: @Mark, Do u know $$(e^h-1)/h=?$$ as $h\to0$

Comment: Yes, I know that. What I don't understand is how you got from where I left at to that expression. What did you do to rewrite it that way?

Comment: @Mark, better set $ x-1=h$